# file has been modified since the precompiled header

Tags: ios

i'm having this llvm error when app is run in simulator,help me to solve this issue
thnqs in advance

file '/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISearchDisplayController.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/sr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JCIIndiaH1-gqpbvvizxkxqsacxykeoxauakjma/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/JCIIndiaH1-Prefix-acfqmfgecxditvcehzyarrulqirr/JCIIndiaH1-Prefix.pch.pch' was built

Comment: I'm not sure if you feel that none of your previous questions have been answered, but I noticed you haven't accepted answers for any of your previously asked questions. Just in case you weren't aware, if you feel that an answer solves a question you ask, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: thanks you for your advice,i'm not fully aware of stack over flow because i'm new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, most users are able to solve this by cleaning their build folder (Product -> Clean Build Folder). However, there have been numerous reports of this happening in Xcode 6. The solution for many is to delete the folder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`.

Comment: Sadly, this was the solution to my issue. How would I guess that? Great answer though, thanks